# C# Removing transparancy from BitmapImage

Tags: c#, 3d, bitmapimage

i'm using a .png as a BitmapImage. The image is being used as a texture on a 3d model.
There is some transparancy in the image which i want to remove.
How do i remove it? (as efficiently as possible, using VisualBrush or System.Drawing.Image is not an option.)

```
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.UriSource = new Uri(fullPath, UriKind.Absolute);
    bi.EndInit();
    bi.Freeze();
    ImageBrush br = new ImageBrush(bi) { Stretch = Stretch.Fill };
    DiffuseMaterial mat = new DiffuseMaterial(br);
```

Comment: Don't. Just use png without transparency or bmp file. Seriously. It's the best solution. Otherwise you may kill your app or lose much performance (it depends on what you're exactly doing)

Comment: unfortunately, that is not a solution. There will be png files with transparency.